# What is the target parameter in amchart adapter

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

I am trying to create a variance chart using amchart4. And I am using the example from the demo.

https://www.amcharts.com/demos/variance-indicators/

What is the actually the target object in each of the below usages on the adapter?

Is it ValueAxis or the CategoryAxis or something else?

```
     // Create axes
    var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
    categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "year";
    categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
    categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 30;
    
    var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
    valueAxis.min = 0;
    
    // Create series
    var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
    series.dataFields.valueY = "value";
    series.dataFields.categoryX = "year";
    
    // Add series for showing variance arrows
    var series2 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
    series2.dataFields.valueY = "valueNext";
    series2.dataFields.openValueY = "value";
    series2.dataFields.categoryX = "year";
    series2.columns.template.width = 1;
    series2.fill = am4core.color("#555");
    series2.stroke = am4core.color("#555");
    
    // Add a triangle for arrow tip
    var arrow = series2.bullets.push(new am4core.Triangle);
    arrow.width = 10;
    arrow.height = 10;
    arrow.horizontalCenter = "middle";
    arrow.verticalCenter = "top";
    arrow.dy = -1;
    
    // Set up a rotation adapter which would rotate the triangle if its a negative change
    arrow.adapter.add("rotation", function(rotation, target) {
      return getVariancePercent(target.dataItem) < 0 ? 180 : rotation;
    });
    
    // Set up a rotation adapter which adjusts Y position
    arrow.adapter.add("dy", function(dy, target) {
      return getVariancePercent(target.dataItem) < 0 ? 1 : dy;
    });
// Add a label
var label = series2.bullets.push(new am4core.Label);
label.padding(10, 10, 10, 10);
label.text = "";
label.fill = am4core.color("#0c0");
label.strokeWidth = 0;
label.horizontalCenter = "middle";
label.verticalCenter = "bottom";
label.fontWeight = "bolder";

// Adapter for label text which calculates change in percent
label.adapter.add("textOutput", function(text, target) {
  var percent = getVariancePercent(target.dataItem);
  return percent ? percent + "%" : text;
});

// Adapter which shifts the label if it's below the variance column
label.adapter.add("verticalCenter", function(center, target) {
  return getVariancePercent(target.dataItem) < 0 ? "top" : center;
});

// Adapter which changes color of label to red
label.adapter.add("fill", function(fill, target) {
  return getVariancePercent(target.dataItem) < 0 ? am4core.color("#c00") : fill;
});

function getVariancePercent(dataItem) {
  if (dataItem) {
    var value = dataItem.valueY;
    var openValue = dataItem.openValueY;
    var change = value - openValue;
    return Math.round(change / openValue * 100);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add an adapter on an object, the first parameter is the value you're modifying and the second parameter, `target`, is an instance of the object that the adapter was added to (if you add `console.log(target.className)` you can see the name of the object class instance). So, in the following snippet:

```
// Set up a rotation adapter which would rotate the triangle if its a negative change
arrow.adapter.add("rotation", function(rotation, target) {
  return getVariancePercent(target.dataItem) < 0 ? 180 : rotation;
});

// Set up a rotation adapter which adjusts Y position
arrow.adapter.add("dy", function(dy, target) {
  return getVariancePercent(target.dataItem) < 0 ? 1 : dy;
});
```

You're adding adapters to all the triangle bullets in the series that modify the `rotation` and `dy` properties of each bullet. The first argument is the property the adapter is modifying (`rotation` and `dy`, respectively) and `target` is the individual bullet instance associated with the data point. Similarly:

```
// Adapter for label text which calculates change in percent
label.adapter.add("textOutput", function(text, target) {
  var percent = getVariancePercent(target.dataItem);
  return percent ? percent + "%" : text;
});

// Adapter which shifts the label if it's below the variance column
label.adapter.add("verticalCenter", function(center, target) {
  return getVariancePercent(target.dataItem) < 0 ? "top" : center;
});

// Adapter which changes color of label to red
label.adapter.add("fill", function(fill, target) {
  return getVariancePercent(target.dataItem) < 0 ? am4core.color("#c00") : fill;
});
```

The `target` in each of of these adapters is the label (bullet) instance associated with the data point in the series.